# Concatenate nested lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have the following list of lists (`list_a` and `list_b`) and the result I want to get (`list_c`), how can I do it?

```
list_a = [[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[101,102,103]]

list_b = [[0],[10],[100]]

list_c = [[0,1,2,3],[10,11,12,13],[100,101,102,103]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension, and add both sublists at each iteration:

```
[b + a for a,b in zip(list_a,list_b)]
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12, 13], [100, 101, 102, 103]]
```

---

Or using `map`:

```
from operator import add
list(map(add, list_a, list_b))
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12, 13], [100, 101, 102, 103]]
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Comment: The `starmap` is redundant here because regular `map` can be used as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36403968/1219006, since we always know it will just be 2 lists. But when it's N lists maybe also as an iterable then `starmap` would be great.

Comment: Thanks for this @jamylak. Wasn't aware that `map` could take two sequences on which to perform the operation. I was trying to figure out how to use `starmap` for multiple sequences in an iterable perhaps as you mentioned. How could that be done? Woudn't `functools.reduce` be necessary for something like that?

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate the sublists within a list comprehension

```
>>> [i + j for i,j in zip(list_b, list_a)]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12, 13], [100, 101, 102, 103]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If using external library is not an issue, you can also try using `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

list_a = [[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[101,102,103]]
list_b = [[0],[10],[100]]
list_c = np.concatenate((list_b, list_a), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do in this way:

```
list_c = [list_b[i] + list_a[i] for i in range(0, len(list_a))] 
list_c
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12, 13], [100, 101, 102, 103]]
```